# Gridsome mounted method is only running on page reload

Tags: vue.js, algolia, gridsome

I am using the vue mounted lifecyle method to fetch data. The data is stored in algolia. I use the search api to connect and fetch it. The data is only loaded when I refresh the site. It does not run on page navigation.

```
methods: {
    async fetchInventory(data = {}) {
        try {
            this.isLoading = true;
            const result = await index.search("", {hitsPerPage: 12});

            this.auctions = result.hits;

            this.totalItems = result.nbHits;
            this.totalPages = result.nbPages;
            this.isLoading = false;
        } catch (error) {
            this.isLoading = false;
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchInventory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is client side rendering you may need to wait until nextTick OR use earlier/later hook:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
  })
}
```

May need to use beforeCreate or created hook if rendering serverside.

Also how is page navigation being done? if you're using navigation API or a library that may be critical to fixing the issue

Comment: Its still not fetching the data. It only shows up in chrome dev tools network tab as a request when I refresh the page not on page navigation.

Comment: Am only rendering cliend side and using Gridsome g-link to navigate between pages.